# Converting Protools 10 to Protools 9 without losing anything

Tags: pro-tools

I have kinda heard that there is a way of converting PT10 PTX to PT 9 without losing anything from your session. When I tried to convert using "save copy as" Protools informed me that I would lose any of my gain changes and my fades.

Is there any way of converting that will avoid any changes to my project?

Comment: Your fades will be saved. Any clip gain changes will be lost unless you render them. HD will give you the option to save out that clip gain data as volume automation, but they obviously can't give away such an important utility to casual users. (sarcasm) If you don't have HD, your best bet is to select your regions, right click, and select "render clip gain". It's destructive, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I've never had ProTools do away with fades when doing a save session as, but I can double check that.  You can either Render clip gain on any clips that use it or if your on ProTools HD you can have it convert clip gain to volume automation which isn't exactly the same thing but might be close enough depending on how your using it and if your going to continue mixing.